# Error executing twice a function that plays a video

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, visual-studio-code, python-3.8

I have a problem that happens when i try to run twice the same function (it's a function that plays a random video from a folder). I discovered the problem when i tried to make a "for loop" that would replay the function a determined amount of times. It doesn't appear a specific error, it just resolves it by the "if statement" that i'm going to show you next

```
if (vid.isOpened()== False):
        print("El archivo de mierda no se pudo abrir")
```

So in my screen just pops up the message "El archivo de mierda no se pudo abrir". If i try to comment out that "if statement", the second time the function it's just ignored and the second video doesn't get played. How do i avoid or solve this? The whole code is the next one:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os, random

nombr = random.choice(os.listdir(r"C:\\Users\\JLHI6\\Desktop\\CODE\\Catu\\videos"))
videa = r"C:\\Users\\JLHI6\\Desktop\\CODE\\Catu\\videos\\" + nombr
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(videa)

def correr_video():    
    if (vid.isOpened()== False):
        print("El archivo de mierda no se pudo abrir")

    while (vid.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = vid.read()
        if ret == True:
            cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
                break

        else:
            break

    vid.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

correr_video()
correr_video()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the function `vid.release()` closes the video ([docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#afb4ab689e553ba2c8f0fec41b9344ae6)), so to play the video a second time you have to reopen it using `vid = cv2.VideoCapture(videa)`

To make it easier to play different video's you can restructure your code a bit:

```
def correr_video(vid_file): 
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_file)
    [rest of code in function]


correr_video(videa)
```